# wxSizers not arranging correctly in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have two `wxTextCtrl`s and two `wxButton`s inside a panel. I want to arrange them using sizers. I want to put the `wxTextCtrl`s to horizontal and the `wxButton`s to vertical. It seems not to work, here's my code:

```
    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this);
    wxPanel* panel2 = new wxPanel(this);
    wxStaticText* u = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "Username");
    uid = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY);
    wxStaticText* p = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, "Password");
    pass = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_PASSWORD);
    wxButton* r = new wxButton(panel, 1, "Register");
    wxStaticLine* line = new wxStaticLine(panel2, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(0,15));
    wxButton* l = new wxButton(panel, 2, "Login");
    //wxDefaultSize, wxTE_MULTILINE | wxHSCROLL | wxTE_READONLY);
    wxBoxSizer* panelSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    panelSizer1->Add(u, wxSizerFlags().Top());
    panelSizer1->Add(uid, wxSizerFlags().Top());
    panelSizer1->Add(p, wxSizerFlags().Top());
    panelSizer1->Add(pass, wxSizerFlags().Top());
    panel->SetSizer(panelSizer1);
    wxBoxSizer* panelSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    panelSizer->Add(l, wxSizerFlags().Center());
    panelSizer->Add(line, wxSizerFlags().Center());
    panelSizer->Add(r, wxSizerFlags().Center());
    panel->SetSizer(panelSizer);
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "*It seems not to work*"?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `panel->SetSizer()` twice, with `panelSizer1` first and then with `panelSizer`, is not going to do anything useful as the second call replaces the sizer set by the first one. You must embed sizers one into the other to achieve the desired layout.

Also, a hint: for a typical 2-column layout with the labels on the left and text controls on the right it is easier to use [wxFlexGridSizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_flex_grid_sizer.html) and not box sizers in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 2 box sizers but you can only set one box sizer to the panel.
According to your requirement I think it's better to add the Horizontal sizer as the 1st element of the vertical sizer.

```
panelSizer1->Add(u, wxSizerFlags().Top());
panelSizer1->Add(uid, wxSizerFlags().Top());
panelSizer1->Add(p, wxSizerFlags().Top());
panelSizer1->Add(pass, wxSizerFlags().Top());

wxBoxSizer* panelSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
panelSizer->Add(panelSizer1, wxSizerFlags().Center());
panelSizer->Add(l, wxSizerFlags().Center());
panelSizer->Add(line, wxSizerFlags().Center());
panelSizer->Add(r, wxSizerFlags().Center());
panel->SetSizer(panelSizer);
```

Try using [wxformbuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) if you have trouble with building UIs with wxWidgets.

cheers !!